# It is possible to get the location of a user just with a call from a cellphone?

Tags: mobile, geolocation

It is possible to get the location of a user just with a call from a cellphone? Are there any APIs or technologies to make this possible?

Comment: They do it all the time on NCIS so it must be possible :o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I am understanding your question, you aren't asking for GPS location, but more like the large area like state or country?  If so, it's possible.  Each number has a country and (at least in the US) an area code.  You can get it from that.  ICS does this by default with numbers from a different area code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only for emergency calls.

For privacy reasons, no-one else can do that.

Comment: My SO worked in our local 911 and they *did not* have this information available. ( So, when you call 911, know where your are at. )

Comment: so just in the web is the only way to get the localisation of a person?

Comment: @starbolin: All cell phones are required by law to send location information to E911 services.